# Passing headers to webRequest as parameter

Tags: c#

If we have generic httpWebRequest method, and if we pass headers through parameter, how can we pass them as string?

Example of method and headers as parameter. How do we pass headers to the method?

```
public static HttpWebResponse PostRequest(string url, string usrname, string pwd, string method, string contentType,
                                       string[] headers, string body)
        {
            // Variables.
            HttpWebRequest Request;
            HttpWebResponse Response;
            //
            string strSrcURI = url.Trim();
            string strBody = body.Trim();

            try
            {
                // Create the HttpWebRequest object.
                Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strSrcURI);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usrname) == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd) == false)
                {
                    // Add the network credentials to the request.
                    Request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usrname.Trim(), pwd);
                }

                // Specify the method.
                Request.Method = method.Trim();

                // request headers
                foreach (string s in headers)
                {
                    Request.Headers.Add(s);
                }

                // Set the content type header.
                Request.ContentType = contentType.Trim();

                // set the body of the request...
                Request.ContentLength = body.Length;
                using (Stream reqStream = Request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    // Write the string to the destination as a text file.
                    reqStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body), 0, body.Length);
                    reqStream.Close();
                }

                // Send the method request and get the response from the server.
                Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();

                // return the response to be handled by calling method...
                return Response;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Web API error: " + e.Message, e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what is your specific question? How to pass parameters to the `PostRequest` method?

Comment: headers is a NameValueCollection or a Dictionary not a string array - you cannot represent key/values with a string array

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream to write content to webrequest:

```
string data = "username=<value>&password=<value>"; //replace <value>
byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
private string urlPath = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/manager/";
string request = urlPath + "index.php/org/get_org_form";
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(request);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;  
Stream newStream=webRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Send the data.
newStream.Write(dataStream,0,dataStream.Length);
newStream.Close();
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```